# .NET WCF serialization issues

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, xml-serialization

The situation: system A is supposed to expose SOAP 1.2 web service for system B to call. In order for A to know what the message looks like, B sent an XSD to A describing the contents of the message. A generated the stubs using the .NET xsd.exe tool, created the simple webservice around this and the job was done.

However; when B calls this webservice, A refuses to serialize the SOAP/XML content to the generated proxy class instances. I realize this must be down to the way the serialization is defined on the webservice side on system A, but have been unable to locate exactly what is going wrong.

**What the message from B looks like (anonymized) - FAILS:**

```
<ns2:Set_Out xmlns:ns2="http://a.a/1.0" xmlns:ns1="http://b.b/1.0" xmlns:ns0="http://c.c">
<Context xmlns="">
    <Foo>test</Foo>
    <Bar>test</Bar>
    ...
</Context>
```

**What a test message from a test client (based on the WSDL) looks like - WORKS:**

```
<Set_Out xmlns="http://a.a/1.0">
<Context xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/x.x" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <b:Foo>TEST</b:Foo>
    <b:Bar>test</b:Bar>
    ...
</Context>
```

When the webservice built by A receives the messages from B, it doesn't serialize the message at all. The objects of the proxy (for instance `Context`) are `null`. When it receives the messages from a test client, everything is generated correctly.

**The serialization attributes on the proxy:**

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://a.a/1.0")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://a.a/1.0", IsNullable=false)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContract]
public partial class Set_Out {
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="http://a.a/1.0", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMember(Order=0)]
    public ContextType Context;
    ...

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://a.a/1.0")]
public partial class ContextType {
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string Foo;
```

Things I find odd:

1. When generating the WSDL for this service, the WSDL adds its own namespaces to the WSDL definition (`xmlns:b` in the example above, for instance).
2. The WSDL doesn't respect the `unqualified` annotations defined in the proxy, and makes everything qualified.

I've tried various combinations of annotations, but nothing seems to help; the messages from B aren't correctly deserialized to the proxies generated by A. Any ideas/pointers/help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Note: the XML examples above are excerpts from the entire message, obviously this includes a lot more SOAP related stuff but I've left that out for brevity.

Comment: Why send XSD? Why not just use "Add Service Reference"?

Comment: I had the same reaction, but I'm consulting for a company and this company is system B in my story, so I avoided the conflict and went along with it.

Comment: In fact this is an inverted way of working; instead of the client adhering to the contract (WSDL), I hacked away at the contract to make the client work. One could argue that's stupid and "doing it wrong".

Comment: @pHk: I would argue that it's unmaintainable, doesn't adhere to standards, and that it's contrary to the long-term interests of your client.

Comment: @John: while I agree with you on all counts, this seems to be the way it's done here, and I'm not about to stick my manparts in that hornets nest. That's a discussion worthy of its own thread entirely though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a typical case of "ask the question, solve it yourself 5 minutes later" I've managed to solve my problem.

The issue was that, apparently, when using WCF .NET uses a default serializer for the classes involved in the data contract. This default serializer (I believe it's `DataContractSerializer`) apparently doesn't really allow much in the way of configuration. I had to tell WCF to use `XmlSerializer` to serialize the message. To do this, I had to add the `[XmlSerializerFormat()]` annotation to the service contract interface (apparently it's meant to work on operations as well). Example:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://a.a/1.0")]
[XmlSerializerFormat()]
public interface IMyWebService
{
    [OperationContract()]
    void DoStuff(Set_Out message);
}
```

After adding the  `[XmlSerializerFormat()]` annotation, the WSDL changed significantly (proper namespaces) and the messages are serialized correctly.

Forum post that set me on the right track: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/c7fede29-56c2-4ff3-bd02-48e3e0b2cec1/

Answer (score 2):

(this is actually a comment, but it can't fit)

Try adding the system.diagnostics to your web.config to find out more information about errors:

```
    <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
                <add name="sdt"
                    type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                    initializeData= "C:\MyLog.svclog" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    </system.diagnostics>
```

You can view the svclog using `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\SvcTraceViewer.exe` (or similar). Add this to both services (different log filenames of course), and see which one fails, and exactly why.

I would suspect that the serialization is OK, but some binding/setting of the service causes the call to fail.

Comment: OK, typical, but I think I have found a solution that seems to work, need to do some more testing, BRB :)