# WCF Service returning "bad" response - Client gets data different than what the server sent

Tags: .net, wcf, wsdl

I'm getting a strange issue with my WCF Service.

I am able to submit a message, and return the result.  The issue I"m having is what the server shows as the response, the client gets a different version.

The client software cannot be changed for this to work. It's based on a WSDL contract, which is what the WCF services were created from.

Update:
It seems that all default NameSpaces we use in our XML are being overwritten by a new default one on the outbound data.

**Service**

```
 [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
 [WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name = "QUPA_AR101102_Binding", Namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3")]
GetDemographicsResponse1 IQUPA_AR101102.HCIM_IN_GetDemographics(Message request)
        {
            HCIM.HIALServices.QUPA_AR101102_Service service = new HIALServices.QUPA_AR101102_Service();

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(request.GetReaderAtBodyContents().ReadOuterXml());

            HCIM.HIALMessaging.GetDemographics gd = new HIALMessaging.GetDemographics(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
            XmlNode gdr = gd.HIALRequest(doc);
        //These 2 lines produce the same data on the server, but the client sees this totally different.
        //HCIM.HL7v3.Objects.QUPA_AR101102.HCIM_IN_GetDemographicsResponse response = this.getMessageObject<HCIM.HL7v3.Objects.QUPA_AR101102.HCIM_IN_GetDemographicsResponse>(gdr.OuterXml, "urn:hl7-org:v3");
        HCIM_IN_GetDemographicsResponse1 r1 = new HCIM_IN_GetDemographicsResponse1(gd.wcfObjectResponse as HCIM.HL7v3.Objects.QUPA_AR101102.HCIM_IN_GetDemographicsResponse);            
       //the above line is a serialized version of the XML - I just packaged it up to` test

        return r1;
    }
```

**Contract**

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3")]
public interface IQUPA_AR101102
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "HCIM_IN_GetDemographics", Action = "urn:hl7-org:v3/QUPA_IN101101")]
    HCIM_IN_GetDemographicsResponse1 HCIM_IN_GetDemographics(Message request);

...
}
```

(The code is just mocking the functionality right now until I get the proper response.)

When I look at the XML that is generated on the server, or the object that is living on the server.

Sample of the XML on the server side it looks like this - I can serialize and deserialize it to and from the HCIM_IN_GetDemograhpics type without any issue or degrading of the data.

**XML/Data from the server I am expecting (not getting)**

```
<HCIM_IN_GetDemographicsResponse xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
    <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.51.1.1.1" extension="404002d6-3978-413d-a49d-b11e240bbf26" />
    <creationTime value="20150204185920" />
    <versionCode code="V3PR1" />
    <interactionId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.51.1.1.2" extension="HCIM_IN_GetDemographicsResponse" />
    <processingCode code="P" />
    <processingModeCode code="T" />
    <acceptAckCode code="NE" />
    <receiver typeCode="RCV">
...
```

When my client recieves this it comes out as something totally different.

**Data I am receiving in XML**

```
<HCIM_IN_GetDemographicsResponse xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/HCIM.HL7v3.Objects.QUPA_AR101102" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <a:acceptAckCode>
        <a:nullFlavor>NI</a:nullFlavor>
        <a:nullFlavorSpecified>false</a:nullFlavorSpecified>
        <a:code>NE</a:code>
        <a:codeSystem i:nil="true" />
        <a:codeSystemName i:nil="true" />
        <a:codeSystemVersion i:nil="true" />
        <a:displayName i:nil="true" />
        <a:originalText i:nil="true" />
        <a:qualifier i:nil="true" />
        <a:translation i:nil="true" />
    </a:acceptAckCode>   
    <a:creationTime>
        <a:nullFlavor>NI</a:nullFlavor>
        <a:nullFlavorSpecified>false</a:nullFlavorSpecified>
        <a:value>20150204185920</a:value>
    </a:creationTime>
    <a:id>
        <a:nullFlavor>NI</a:nullFlavor>
        <a:nullFlavorSpecified>false</a:nullFlavorSpecified>
        <a:assigningAuthorityName i:nil="true" />
        <a:displayable>false</a:displayable>
        <a:displayableSpecified>false</a:displayableSpecified>
        <a:extension>404002d6-3978-413d-a49d-b11e240bbf26</a:extension>
        <a:root>2.16.840.1.113883.3.51.1.1.1</a:root>
    </a:id>
    <a:interactionId>
        <a:nullFlavor>NI</a:nullFlavor>
        <a:nullFlavorSpecified>false</a:nullFlavorSpecified>
        <a:assigningAuthorityName i:nil="true" />
        <a:displayable>false</a:displayable>
        <a:displayableSpecified>false</a:displayableSpecified>
        <a:extension>HCIM_IN_GetDemographicsResponse</a:extension>
        <a:root>2.16.840.1.113883.3.51.1.1.2</a:root>
    </a:interactionId>
    <a:nullFlavor i:nil="true" />
    ...
```

**Current web config:**

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <!-- Secure Bindings -->
        <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>

        <binding name="httpBinding">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <!--Synchronous Services-->
      <!--Get Demographics/FindCandidates/GetRelatedIdentifiers Service-->
      <service name="HCIM.Services.Synchronous.QUPA_AR101102" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding" contract="HCIM.Services.Synchronous.Contracts.IQUPA_AR101102"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpBinding" contract="HCIM.Services.Synchronous.Contracts.IQUPA_AR101102" />
      </service>
```

**Cut-Down WSDL** original is 19,000 lines long. the Elements that have xsd:anyType point to a concrete element in the schema. One client modified this as such so they could use XML in that section. If I could get this WCF working with a WSDL like this it would suffice.

```
<wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns:hl7="urn:hl7-org:v3">
            <xs:element name="GetDemographics" type="xsd:anyType"/>
            <xs:element name="GetDemographicsResponse" type="xsd:anyType"/>
            <xs:element name="FindCandidates" type="xsd:anyType"/>
            <xs:element name="FindCandidatesResponse" type="xsd:anyType"/>
            <xs:element name="GetRelatedIdentifiers" type="xsd:anyType"/>
            <xs:element name="GetRelatedIdentifiersResponse" type="xsd:anyType"/>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="GetDemographicsSoapIn">
        <wsdl:documentation>HCIM Get Person Demographics Query (localized QUPA_IN101101) </wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:part name="body" element="tns:GetDemographics"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetDemographicsSoapOut">
        <wsdl:documentation>HCIM Get Person Demographics Response (localized QUPA_IN101102)</wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:part name="body" element="tns:GetDemographicsResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="FindCandidatesSoapIn">
        <wsdl:documentation>HCIM Find Candidates Query (localized QUPA_IN101103) </wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:part name="body" element="tns:FindCandidates"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="FindCandidatesSoapOut">
        <wsdl:documentation>HCIM Find Candidates Response (localized QUPA_IN101104)</wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:part name="body" element="tns:FindCandidatesResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetRelatedIdentifiersSoapIn">
        <wsdl:documentation>HCIM Get Related Identifiers Query (localized QUPA_IN101105) </wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:part name="body" element="tns:GetRelatedIdentifiers"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetRelatedIdentifiersSoapOut">
        <wsdl:documentation>HCIM Get Related Identifers Response (localized QUPA_IN101106)</wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:part name="body" element="tns:GetRelatedIdentifiersResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="QUPA_AR101102_PortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="GetDemographics">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:GetDemographicsSoapIn"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:GetDemographicsSoapOut"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="FindCandidates">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:FindCandidatesSoapIn"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:FindCandidatesSoapOut"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetRelatedIdentifiers">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:GetRelatedIdentifiersSoapIn"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:GetRelatedIdentifiersSoapOut"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="QUPA_AR101102_Binding" type="tns:QUPA_AR101102_PortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetDemographics">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:hl7-org:v3/QUPA_IN101101"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="FindCandidates">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:hl7-org:v3/QUPA_IN101103"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetRelatedIdentifiers">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:hl7-org:v3/QUPA_IN101105"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
```

I have tried changing the return types, container types etc. Nothing is working.  I tried to implement my WCF service to just accept and return XMLNodes but that failed.

The data is being sent out properly, but .NET is changing it somehow and I'm not sure how/why.

The default namespace of the incoming message is:  urn:hl7-org:v3
The output that is being sent is using the wrong namespace: xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/HCIM.HL7v3.Objects.QUPA_AR101102"

I added:

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract(Namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3")]
```

To the HCIM_IN_GetDemograhpicsResponse object, but now the result in the client is just null for every attribute.

Is there a way to have a string type as the input/output typeof this WCF service where connecting devices don't need to change their binding/code (They're bound to the WSDL contract).

Comment: Do you have a wsdl link?

Comment: I'll have to thin the WSDL out, not allowed to share the full thing (19000 lines long). Is there a way of modifying the service to return XML rather than the a Type based off of Message without wrecking the contract?

Comment: Ah, the joy of HL7v3... I know it well!

Comment: It seems it's doing this on all WCF services generated from a WSDL - it's not recognizing the default namespace and thus the output seems to be corrupt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF .NET uses DataContractSerializer by default. You can override this by adding the [XmlSerializerFormat()] annotation.
Instead of adding the annotation to generated file you can generate using the /serializer:XmlSerializer switch.

So when generating the classes do this to use XMLSerializer rather than the DataContract serializer:

svcutil QUPA_AR101102.wsdl /serializer:XmlSerializer /fault

Answer (score 0):

This Stack OVerflow question answered this one:
[.NET WCF serialization issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730809/net-wcf-serialization-issues)

When generating from a WSDL (SOAP) for WCF I needed to use the serializer command:
svcutil QUPA_AR101102.wsdl /serializer:XmlSerializer /fault